# Android: String.split() method not actually splitting?

Tags: java, android

Maybe it's been a long day and I've overlooked something, but this is driving me absolutely crazy.

```
String[] address = "192.169.2.10".split(".");
Log.d(TAG, "Address array length: "+address.length); 
//Output: 'Address array length: 0'
```

I am resolving the device IP address, and trying to split it into an `String` array by splitting it on the period characters. Obviously this should return an array with a length of 4, but it's returning a length of 0.

Is there something blatantly obvious I am overlooking here?

NOTE: The real code is pulling that IP address in from `WifiManager`, but even if I put an arbitrary IP String in there like above, the length is 0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The argument to [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) is a regular expression, and the `.` has a special meaning, so you'll need to escape it:

```
String[] address = "192.169.2.10".split("\\.");
```